# How to get the maximum values for higher hierarchical data in a matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I was having trouble to get the row maximum in a hierarchical table.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrxZF.png)

C19 is a section that contains the C191, C192 and C193 divisions, and the C191 division contains a group called 411, C192 contains a group called 412 and C193 contains two groups - 283 and 413. I am trying to get the row maximum at the higher hierarchical level as well. However Power BI is showing the maximum values for the group level at the section level as well. How do I solve this problem ?

a screenshot of the data to recreate the situation:

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L8Rd.png)

The correct maximum values should be:8400020 for C19, 6136706 for C191 and group 411,  446113 for C192 and group 412, 1934805 for C193 and 193106 for group 283 and 1741699 for group 413

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you include the values you would like to see in your first image? It seems to me that the behaviour you want is allready there.

Comment: Hi @MarcoVos, the correct numbers should be 8400020 for C19, 6136706 for C191 and group 411, 446113 for C192 and group 412, 1934805 for C193 and 193106 for group 283 and 1741699 for group 413.  Power BI only calculated the maximum at the group level, not at the higher levels.